# Canvas Snow Animation does not work

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

So a season specific question. I have made a basic animation to simulate some snow. The problem is that the snow only falls once and the screen stays black after that. I have followed a tutorial which put everything inside the window.onload(). THis seems not as good style to me so here is what i came up with:

```js
let sky, ctx;
let W, H;

const maxSnow = 250;
const snow = [];

function init(){
 sky = document.getElementById("sky");
 ctx = sky.getContext("2d");

 sky.width = W = window.innerWidth;
 sky.height = H = window.innerHeight;

 for(let i = 0; i < maxSnow; i++)
 {
  snow.push({
   x: Math.random()*W, //x-coordinate
   y: -50, //y-coordinate
   radius: Math.random()*4+1, //radius
   density: Math.random()*maxSnow //density
  })
 }
}

function draw()
{
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

 ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
 ctx.beginPath();
 for(let i = 0; i < maxSnow; i++)
 {
  var flake = snow[i];
  ctx.moveTo(flake.x, flake.y);
  ctx.arc(flake.x, flake.y, flake.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
 }
 ctx.fill();
 update();
}

//Function to move the snowflakes
//angle will be an ongoing incremental flag. Sin and Cos functions will be applied to it to create vertical and horizontal movements of the flakes
var angle = 0;
function update()
{
 angle += 0.01;
 for(var i = 0; i < maxSnow; i++)
 {
  var p = snow[i];
  //Updating X and Y coordinates
  //We will add 1 to the cos function to prevent negative values which will lead flakes to move upwards
  //Every particle has its own density which can be used to make the downward movement different for each flake
  //Lets make it more random by adding in the radius
  p.y += Math.cos(angle+p.density) + 1 + p.radius/2;
  p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;

  //Sending flakes back from the top when it exits
  //Lets make it a bit more organic and let flakes enter from the left and right also.
  if(p.x > W+5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H)
  {
   if(i%3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
   {
    snow[i] = {x: Math.random()*W, y: -10, r: p.radius, d: p.density};
   }
   else
   {
    //If the flake is exitting from the right
    if(Math.sin(angle) > 0)
    {
     //Enter from the left
     snow[i] = {x: -5, y: Math.random()*H, r: p.radius, d: p.density};
    }
    else
    {
     //Enter from the right
     snow[i] = {x: W+5, y: Math.random()*H, r: p.radius, d: p.density};
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

window.onload = function(){
 init();
 //animation loop
 setInterval(draw, 33);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  sky.width = W = window.innerWidth;
  sky.height = H = window.innerHeight;
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="sky"></canvas>
    <script src="snow.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anybody see what the problem is and why the particles are only falling once?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The is because when the snow flakes exit the screen you reset them to a wrong object.

You original object (and all methods) expect `x`,`y`,`radius` and `density`

But when you update the object you create `x`,`y`, `r` and `d`.

If you rename `r` and `d` to the correct names it works.

```js
let sky, ctx;
let W, H;

const maxSnow = 250;
const snow = [];

function init(){
 sky = document.getElementById("sky");
 ctx = sky.getContext("2d");

 sky.width = W = window.innerWidth;
 sky.height = H = window.innerHeight;

 for(let i = 0; i < maxSnow; i++)
 {
  snow.push({
   x: Math.random()*W, //x-coordinate
   y: -50, //y-coordinate
   radius: Math.random()*4+1, //radius
   density: Math.random()*maxSnow //density
  })
 }
}

function draw()
{
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);

 ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)";
 ctx.beginPath();
 for(let i = 0; i < maxSnow; i++)
 {
  var flake = snow[i];
  ctx.moveTo(flake.x, flake.y);
  ctx.arc(flake.x, flake.y, flake.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
 }
 ctx.fill();
 update();
}

//Function to move the snowflakes
//angle will be an ongoing incremental flag. Sin and Cos functions will be applied to it to create vertical and horizontal movements of the flakes
var angle = 0;
function update()
{
 angle += 0.01;
 for(var i = 0; i < maxSnow; i++)
 {
  var p = snow[i];
  //Updating X and Y coordinates
  //We will add 1 to the cos function to prevent negative values which will lead flakes to move upwards
  //Every particle has its own density which can be used to make the downward movement different for each flake
  //Lets make it more random by adding in the radius
  p.y += Math.cos(angle+p.density) + 1 + p.radius/2;
  p.x += Math.sin(angle) * 2;

  //Sending flakes back from the top when it exits
  //Lets make it a bit more organic and let flakes enter from the left and right also.
  if(p.x > W+5 || p.x < -5 || p.y > H)
  {
   if(i%3 > 0) //66.67% of the flakes
   {
    snow[i] = {x: Math.random()*W, y: -10, radius: p.radius, density: p.density};
   }
   else
   {
    //If the flake is exitting from the right
    if(Math.sin(angle) > 0)
    {
     //Enter from the left
     snow[i] = {x: -5, y: Math.random()*H, radius: p.radius, density: p.density};
    }
    else
    {
     //Enter from the right
     snow[i] = {x: W+5, y: Math.random()*H, radius: p.radius, density: p.density};
    }
   }
  }
 }
}

window.onload = function(){
 init();
 //animation loop
 setInterval(draw, 33);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
  sky.width = W = window.innerWidth;
  sky.height = H = window.innerHeight;
}, false);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <canvas id="sky"></canvas>
    <script src="snow.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```